# How to detect if the values are same or different in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Please help me, how to detect if the values are the same or not? I have a script that automatically open a new browser tab for Google Maps and search the detected home address. But, what if there's a two different address? How to detect it? I have two types of home address, one is contact address and second, permanent address. There's a time that those types of address have different values. If permanent address is detect that have a different values it will open a new separate browser tab for Google Maps. In short, if the two types of home address are both different in each other, it will open two Google Maps. One for Contact and one for Permanent. Please help me. Thank you

Here's the script of detecting of address:

```
 function scanLapVerification() {
    try {
        //check if the page is activity where address check is done
        var page_title = "Title";
        var el = getElement(document, "class", "view-operator-verification-title", "");
        if (!el || el.length == 0) return;
        if (el[0].innerText != page_title) return;
        var page_title = '';
        var el = getElement(document, "class", "workflowActivityDetailPanel", "");
        if (el && el.length > 0) {
            var eltr = getElement(el[0], "tag", "tr", "");
            if (eltr && eltr.length > 0) {
                //Read Contact and Permanent address
                var addresses = {
                    CA: { province: null, municipality: null, barangay: null, zip: null, street: null, snumber: null, building: null, floor: null }
                   ,PA: { province: null, municipality: null, barangay: null, zip: null, street: null, building: null, bnumber: null, floor: null }
                };
                var address_type = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < eltr.length; i++) {
                    tr_text = eltr[i].innerText;
                    if (tr_text.substr(0, "Contact address".length) == "Contact address") address_type = "CA";
                    if (tr_text.substr(0, "Permanent address".length) == "Permanent address") address_type = "PA";
                    if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Province".length) == "Province") {
                        addresses[address_type].province = tr_text.substr("Province".length + 1, tr_text.length - "Province".length - 1);
                    }
                    if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Barangay".length) == "Barangay") {
                        addresses[address_type].barangay = tr_text.substr("Barangay".length + 1, tr_text.length - "Barangay".length - 1);
                    }
                    if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "ZIP Code".length) == "ZIP Code") {
                        addresses[address_type].zip = tr_text.substr("ZIP Code".length, tr_text.length - "ZIP Code".length);
                    }
                    if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Street name".length) == "Street name") {
                        addresses[address_type].street = tr_text.substr("Street name".length, tr_text.length - "Street name".length);
                    }
                }
            var contact_address = addresses.CA.street
                                + '' + addresses.CA.barangay 
                                + '' + addresses.CA.province
                                + '' + addresses.CA.zip;
            contact_address = contact_address.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
            return { content: "address_check", contact_address: contact_address, permanent_address: null };
        }
    }
    return { status: "KO" };
} catch (e) {
        alert("Exception: scanLapVerification\n" + e.Description);
    return { status: "KO", message: e };
}
};
```

Here's the script for open a new browser tab:

```
 function scanLapVerification() {
 msgbox("sendRequest: scanLapVerification");
 chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabLapVerification, { method: "scanLapVerification" },
    function (response) {
        msgbox("receiveResponse: scanLapVerification " + jsonToString(response, "JSON"));
        // maintaining state in the background
        if (response.data.content == "address_check") {
            //open google maps with request for contact address
             var gmaps;
                if (confirm("Do you want to proceed on Google Maps and search for Contact Address?") == true) {
                gmaps = tabCreate("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(response.data.contact_address));
            } else {
               gmaps = "You Cancel!";
            }
            document.getElementById("maps").innerText = gmaps;
        }
    }
);
}
```

Comment: The "detect if values are the same" feature of JavaScript is called the equality operator or `===`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant can you elaborate? And how to do that? I'm newbie in that PL :( help me

Comment: Well you could start by returning the permanent address when it exists instead of always returning null, and add something like if(response.data.permanent_address){/*open tab*/} in your second function

Comment: @lazertyuiopl where can i add that? can you give the right code, pls?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're trying to do a deep equality check of two objects, which returns true if all properties of both objects are the same. If you can use a third party library, you can try using the [isEqual function of Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual). There are some other options discussed here: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)